# jQuery-UI Draggable and Sortable, beforeStop helper already run

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When the beforeStop singal fires the `ui.item` is equal to `ui.helper`, i.e. the item has already replaced by the helper and I'm unable to access the draggable originating the event.

this is the JavaScript

```
makeDraggable = function(ID) {
    $('ul#elements > li.element').each(function() {
        $(this).draggable({
            helper: function() {
                return $('<div style="height: 100px; width: 300px; background: #F9FAFA; box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); text-align: center; line-height: 100px; font-size: 28px; color: #16A085"><span class="fui-list"></span></div>');
            },
            revert: 'invalid',
            appendTo: 'body',
            connectToSortable: ID,
        });
    });
};

makeSortable = function(el) {
    el.sortable({
        revert: true,
        placeholder: 'drop-hover',
        beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.item);
            console.log(ui.helper);
        },
    });
};

makeDraggable('#page1');
makeSortable($('#page1'));
```

and this is the draggable:

```
<li class="element element_0 ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: list-item;">
    <img src="http://localhost:8000/images/thumbs/header10.png" data-src="http://localhost:8000/elements/header10.html" data-height="567" alt="Site Block">
</li>
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Where is `#page1` ..? Are you initializing the same elements as draggable and sortable..?

Comment: Dropped your code [into a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8do6e7xc/) and it works as expected. The posted code is okay; could you reproduce the issue in a MCVE?

Comment: @TJ not, note that makeDraggable receives the ID of sortable to connectTo, and makeSortable receives a jQuery object to make sortable.

Comment: @blgt really it works :O, but for reason of no time I've workaround it using the 'clone' helper in the draggable and in beforeStop of sortable I've created my custom html and appended to `ui.item.parent()` and so removed `ui.item` and the finally result becomes better since I seen what I'm dragging instead of just only a placeholder.